# How to use b2sum in keyed mode?

Tags: openssl, hashing, cryptography

Considering using Blake2 (perhaps `b2sum`) in conjunction to `openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac $key` but I don’t see an option to enable keyed mode.

Comment: Thanks @MaartenBodewes. Put simply, I don't understand why the specs [mention](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7693#section-1) keyed mode, but the feature hasn’t been implemented in [b2sum](https://github.com/BLAKE2/BLAKE2/tree/master/b2sum) which is part of the official implementation. Or perhaps I am looking at the problem through the lens of LibreSSL and no key is required in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use keys in normal `b2sum` but I was kind enough to add a few command-line options to the program to use keyed-mode (and spec-compliant HMAC, for people who still want HMAC with BLAKE2b)

You can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/Serpent27/BLAKE2/tree/master/b2sum) and build from source.